# Wicket palette with dropdownchoice

Tags: wicket

I created a palette which contains values, and i created a DropDownChoice ddcdomaines with an AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior to update choice list, but i dont know how to do it, can you help me?

Here my code:

```
List<PartnerDomainDTO> domaines = partenaireHelper.allDomains();
    ChoiceRenderer choiceRenderer = new ChoiceRenderer("label", "sid");

    final Palette palette =
        new Palette("partenaires", new PropertyModel(offre, "partenaires"), new Model(
            (Serializable) partenairesPossibles), renderer, 10, false) {
          private static final long serialVersionUID = 1178320215146881229L;

          boolean first = true;

          @Override
          public Iterator getSelectedChoices() {
            if (first) {
              first = false;
              return partenairesExistants.iterator();
            }
            return super.getSelectedChoices();
          }
        };
    palette.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    palette.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);

    DropDownChoice ddcdomaines = new DropDownChoice("domaines", new Model(domaines.get(0)), domaines, choiceRenderer);

    ddcdomaines.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {
      @Override
      protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        remove(palette);
        Palette palette1 =
            new Palette(
                "partenaires",
                new PropertyModel(offre, "partenaires"),
                new Model(new ArrayList<Partenaire>()),
                renderer,
                10,
                false);
        palette1.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        palette1.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
        add(palette1);
        target.addComponent(palette);
        target.addComponent(palette1);
      }
    });
    add(palette);
    add(ddcdomaines);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an excellent example of DropDownChoice with AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior:

http://wicketstuff.org/wicket/ajax/choice

Click on the Source Code link to see the source.  If you need more information, than you need to provide more detail in your question.

**Update**:  According to the JavaDoc, there is a specific way to update Palettes using Ajax:

http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/extensions/markup/html/form/palette/Palette.html

Make sure you follow those instructions before doing anything else.

In your code, you are attempting to remove one Palette and put in another Palette.  While this might work in the long run, it is not very Wicket-y.  Sadly, Palette does not have a public method to change the choices.  However, if you keep a reference to your choicesModel, then you can modify that list and the Palette should see the change on re-render.  Something like this:

```
final Model<List<String>> choicesModel = new Model<List<String>>(partenairesPossibles)

final Palette palette = new Palette("partenaires", new PropertyModel(offre, "partenaires"), choicesModel, renderer, 10, false) {...};
```

And then in your Ajax onUpdate

```
choicesModel.setObject(/* Insert your other list */);
target.addComponent(palette);
```

Be careful with keeping track of the selected choices and the possible choices.  I'm not sure what will happen if these don't match up.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, yes i tried to do like the example using (dropdownchoice and palette) but i couldn't have the result i want, i even tried to make a simple action like setVisible(true or false), so i can hide the palette but when setVisible was true there was nothing, it was still hidden! Have you any idea about this?

Comment: Have you called `setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag( true )` on the palette? It is required for every component that is hidden and shown again using Ajax calls.

Comment: @Mohamed Feel free to edit your original post by showing some of your code.  There are about 1.83 Billion things that might be wrong :)

Comment: @jbrookover Thank you, i thought that only setOutputMarkupId is required for hidden components. Well now it works when i add setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag and i will put my code to show my code and what i would do :)

Comment: @Mohamed Hope that update helps.  I haven't used Palettes at all - they seem pretty restricted.  Google searches for changing the list turn up all sorts of issues.